# Prevent HTML caching on certain pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, browser-cache

I am trying to cache only my assets and not the actual HTML page for a couple of pages on my site.

Currently my cache control header is set to this:

```
cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate
```

my .htaccess file

```
# 1 Day for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|JPG|woff)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

On mobile, when a user opens my site browses to a given page, closes their browser app and then reopens, the page is loaded from cache.

When I set the following headers the mobile browser properly reloads the page when the browser is reopened, but now it reloads everything (javascript, css, images, etc). I only want the html to reload.

```
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store"
response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Updated .htaccess file

```
<IffilesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|JPG|woff)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</If>
<Else>
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires = "0"
Header set Expires = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
Header set Cache-Control = "no-cache, no-store"
</Else>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the full set of headers to ensure that you're hitting all browsers.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

This usually covers multiple issues with cross-browser compatibility including mobile.

Comment: Can you please review the .htaccess file I've updated in the question to reflect your answer?

Comment: None of this seems to work in a ASPX file (a static HTML page renamed to ASPX). Any ideas?